# How to solve the error C2512?

Tags: visual-c++, constructor, c++-cli

I had solved the problem of headers including in each other

But I had this new error c2512. Here is my code:

"rstc.h"

```
public ref class rstc : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
    ref class ddc;
public:

    rstc(System::Windows::Forms::Form ^ y)
    {otherform = y;
        InitializeComponent();

    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::Form ^ otherform;

/////////////////////////////////

         ddc ^ x2 = gcnew ddc(this);//////is here where the error is pointed
         x2->Show();
         this->Hide();
```

"ddc.h"

```
public ref class ddc : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
    ref class rstc;
public:

    ddc(System::Windows::Forms::Form ^ y)
    {otherform = y;
        InitializeComponent();

    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::Form ^ otherform;
```

And this code to go to the other form "rstc"

```
         rstc ^ x2 = gcnew rstc(this);
         x2->Show();
         this->Hide();
```

And the error C2227 I think is related to the first one
Here is the full error

```
error C2512: 'final::ddc::rstc' : no appropriate default constructor available
```

Comment: Please don't make us go do research on MSDN just to know what you're asking about. Show the full error messages you're getting, not just the error number.

Comment: I just added the error code.

Comment: It looks like the problem is in the class named `ddc`, that you have a variable named `rstc` that is missing the `^`.

Comment: I check it  but i didn't figure it out, i just added the code of "ddc.h" if it will make things more clear

Comment: Are you showing us the line from your code that the error message is pointing you to? The message indicates that you have *something* named `final::ddc::rstc`, and I can't re-create the issue with the code you've posted.

Comment: That said, having the forward declaration of a ref class inside of another ref class is non-standard. Move it outside and see if that helps anything.

Comment: I moved it out but it doesn't work.The error is in "ddc" when I want to go to the "rstc" .Thank you for help :)

Comment: Post a short, complete, compilable example that reproduces the problem.